# Kendo Grid Custom Delete confirmation messages

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui, grid

I am using Kendo MVVM. I have a grid with basic functionalities like Add, Edit Delete. For delete, I use the below code. I get a javascript confirmation message when I click on delete. Instead, I need a Kendo Confirmation message with customized text. Can someone help me with this?

My code for delete.

```
,{
    command: [{
         name: 'destroy',
         text: ''
   }]                       
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find information on this functionality in the Kendo UI for JQuery documentation page [Customize Confirmation Window](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/custom-delete-confirmation-dialog)

> To achieve this behavior, use the Kendo UI templates, the Window, and the **remove** dataSource method of Grid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, It is not MVVM though. I tried to implement that way but in vain

Comment: Can you mock up the problem in Dojo or jsFiddle?  My understanding is that Telerik considers grid a MVVM, albeit one that is a special case with special handling beyond standard MVVM.